# How do I use Google assistant to trigger my application

Tags: android, mobile-application, google-assistant-sdk

I am trying to build a simple app which can be triggered by google assistant.
Like if the users say, "Hey Google, Open TestApp" or "Hey Google, perform xyz from TestApp".
What would be the best approach? Dialogflow?

Comment: Doesn't the app do now? Just make your app and install and say that..

Comment: @Xenolion: I tried the simplest command: "Hey Google, Open TestApp". It did not do anything. Do I need to deploy the release version?

Comment: I never tried though, it maybe requires release version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Saying "Okay, Google - do [something] with [your app]" in order to open your app to fulfill a query is called a Google Voice Action and you can add these to your app quite easily. See the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/voice-actions/system/) for full details. Keep in mind - for these to work, your app does need to be in the Play Store, uploaded as a beta at the very least.

The Google Assistant is a little bit different - it's more conversational and doesn't take the user directly to your app. Instead, it takes the user's input, looks for the appropriate app to handle the query, feeds the query to your app, and then returns the response, within Google Assistant itself. This is all about having a conversation with an app, from the Google Assistant, without actually opening up your app.

Comment: @TasnimKhan were you successful doing this, if yes could you provide a sample project

Comment: Yes, I was.
The project is not with me at present. But I will positively post a sample project, this weekend