# Open my application via google assistant using response from dialogflow

Tags: java, android, dialogflow-es

I have android apps that needs to open via google assistant and that has been success. What I want now is talking to google assistant, then google assistant send to dialog flow and then using response from dialog flow to open my android apps via google assistant.

Current:
Google Assistant (Open My Android Apps) -> Opening My Android Apps.

What I want is:
Google Assistant -> DialogFlow (Using the intent for response) -> Google Assistant (Catch response) -> (Use the response to Open My Android Apps).

Is that possible to use response from DialogFlow to open My Android Apps?

Comment: You should review the [links in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56103900/295004) and see if your use case fits.

Comment: Thanks for your response @MorrisonChang, but the link just describes how to open the apps through google assistant (seems like current flow), not as I expected. are there any other references?

Comment: [Dialogflow/Google Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational) is cloud based only. I don't believe you can get Google Assistant to send an Intent different than described in my link. You can have your cloud based Google Action communicate with your app (via HTTP/Firebase Cloud Messaging) if your backend ties the two together.

Comment: So you mean to open my application from google action just can only be done by triggering the FCM directly into my application? Can't pass an intent from google actions to google assistant? @MorrisonChang

Comment: You can launch your app via [App Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant/app/overview) but no interaction with dialogflow. [Your Google Action](https://developers.google.com/assistant) lives in the cloud and talks through dialogflow but doesn't launch an App (as that behavior doesn't work with a speaker or on iOS) Your Google Action can communicate with your backend which your Android app can communicate with.

Comment: @Agus Suryanto  Its is possible to Open my application via google assistant using response from dialogflow ?